# Website in internet explorer 10 compatibily modus display

Tags: internet-explorer, cross-browser, internet-explorer-10

I have a website. If i browse the website with internet explorer 10 i would like that the site will be shown in the IE10 Compatibility mode.

How can i do this in my html site?

Can anybody help me ?

Comment: IE10 has several compatibility modes. Which one did you want to use? There is not an IE10-compatibility mode in IE10, but there is an IE7-compat mode, and IE8-compat mode and an IE9-compat mode, as well as quirks mode. But bear in mind that none of the compat modes are actually the same as a real copy of IE7/8/9 -- there are significant differences that could break your code. My advice: You would be better off making your site work in IE10 standards mode than trying to use compat mode.

Answer (score 0):

If you want your page to render in an older document mode, you can add this to your markup, early inside the HEAD tag:

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=EmulateIE7">
```

Generally speaking, however, you should consider updating your page to use standards-compliant markup.